# Why is the video overlapping the container?

Tags: html, css

If you extend the result window, the video overlaps the section below it.

I want the video to stay within the height of the section, in this case `height:100vh`.

How would I go about this? [Here's a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8ozs1uka/5/).

```
* {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

.Page-01 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #0000ff;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 15;
}

.Page-02 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #FFFF00;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    z-index: 15;
}

#videowrapper {
    padding-bottom: 56.2%;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 15;
    height: 0;
}

#videowrapper iframe {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.Page-03 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #FF0000;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 15;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is some odd stuff going on there because `#videowrapper iframe` is set to `height: 100%;` but its parent's height is `#videowrapper { height: 0; padding-bottom: 56.2%;`

Try setting this instead:

```
#videowrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 15;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! But if I remove the padding-bottom:56.2%, then the video doesn't scale proportionately. Basically I just want the video to be responsive and fit within its container. Any ideas?

Comment: It seems to scale to fit `.Page-02` for me as I resize width and height. (Chrome on OSX)

Comment: Can you demonstrate it on jsfiddle? It scales to fit the container for me but doesn't retain the 16:9 proportion?